# How can I recover damaged FAT12 disk image?

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery, file-recovery

So a damaged disk image with FAT12 filesystem is given, which FATs and RootDir is empty but content of files are still existed in clusters. How can I recover this damaged disk image?

I tried to use testdisk but it ended up being not recovering.

I assume it is possible to recover these file by manually, means edit rootdir and FATs by using hex editor, but it is very time-consuming.

Is there any better way to solve this situation?

Comment: Use the companion to testdisk, called photorec.

Comment: From a quick Google: Lots of data recovery tools support FAT12. http://www.r-studio.com/ is one

Answer (score 0):

The FAT filesystems are easily accessed by the majority of modern operating systems.  You could use a Linux distrubution (such as [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)) to temporarily access the drive.

Download the LiveCD, burn it to a disc, boot your computer from it (make sure you select the `Try before installing` option), and mount the drive.